# How to solve two implicit functions with two variables and parameters

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, mathematical-optimization, code-request

I have two functions given as;

`u[c_,d_] := Sinh[a b^2 c^2 + 3a b d]` and  `v[c_,d_] := Log[a b^2 c^2 + 3a b d + d^2] - d`. I want to find the root of these two functions that maximise another function say `w[c_,d_]:= 2a b c + 3b c - 2c d^2 + c*Exp[a+b]`.
Here, `a` and `b` are parameters that lie between [-3,3] and [1,2] respectively, while c and d are the variables of interest. I am able to solve for `c` and `d` when I use the FindRoot command and fix `a` and `b` (example, a = 1 and b = 0.7).

```
a=1; b=0.7;
FindRoot[{u[c,d]== 0,v[c,d]== 0},{c,0},{d,0}]
```

When I do this I get only one root of the problem and as I change the initial point I get one of the other roots and so on. And I am also able to determine the `c` and `d` that gives the max of `w[c,d]`. But this is what I want to do;

I want to be able to estimate `c` and `d` over the entire space of `a` and `b` and find the point ({c,d}) which maximises `w[c,d]`. Also, to plot the surface of `u[c,d]` with the `c` and  `d` that gives the maximum of `w[c,d]`.

I am new to mathematical and your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
u[c_, d_] := Sinh[a b^2 c^2 + 3 a b d];
v[c_, d_] := Log[a b^2 c^2 + 3 a b d + d^2] - d;
w[c_, d_] := 2 a b c + 3 b c - 2 c d^2 + c*Exp[a + b];
NMaximize[{w[c, d], u[c, d] == 0, v[c, d] == 0, -3 <= a <= 3, 
  1 <= b <= 2}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> `{98.4569, {a -> 2.99992, b -> 1.14721, c -> 1.35641, d -> -0.703619}}`

Comment: Your response is very helpful. Thank you!